# Why is coreutils sort slower than Python?

Tags: python, performance, sort, coreutils, benchmark

I wrote the following script to test the speed of Python's sort functionality:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
lines = list(stdin)
lines.sort()
stdout.writelines(lines)
```

I then compared this to the coreutils `sort` command on a file containing 10 million lines:

```
$ time python sort.py <numbers.txt >s1.txt
real    0m16.707s
user    0m16.288s
sys     0m0.420s

$ time sort <numbers.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m45.141s
user    2m28.304s
sys     0m0.380s
```

The built-in command used all four CPUs (Python only used one) but took about 3 times as long to run!  What gives?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 (32-bit), Python 2.7.3, and `sort` 8.13

Comment: @goldilocks Yes it is, look at the user vs real time.

Comment: Huh -- you're right.  Apparently it was parallelized in coreutils 8.6.

Comment: Can you use `--buffer-size` to specify that `sort` use all available physical memory and see if that helps?

Comment: @1_CR Tried it with 1 GB buffer, no significant change in timing.  It only used about .6 GB of that, so increasing the buffer size further wouldn't help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Izkata's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169739/why-is-coreutils-sort-slower-than-python#comment279814_169747) revealed the answer: locale-specific comparisons. The `sort` command uses the locale indicated by the environment, whereas Python defaults to a byte order comparison. Comparing UTF-8 strings is harder than comparing byte strings.

```
$ time (LC_ALL=C sort <numbers.txt >s2.txt)
real    0m5.485s
user    0m14.028s
sys     0m0.404s
```

How about that.

Comment: And how do they compare for UTF-8 strings?

Comment: @Gilles Modifying the Python script to use `locale.strxfrm` to sort, the script took ~32 seconds, still faster than `sort` but much less so.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 is doing byte comparison, but Python3 would be doing unicode word comparison. Python3.3 is about twice as slow Python2.7 for this "test". The overhead of packing the raw bytes into Unicode representation is even higher than the already significant packing objects that Python 2.7.3 has to do.

Comment: I found the same slow-down with `cut`, and others too. On several machines I now have `export LC_ALL=C` in `.bashrc`. But beware: this essentially breaks `wc` (except `wc -l`), just to name an example. "Bad bytes" are not counted at all...

Comment: This performance problem also occurs with `grep`: you can get a *substantial* performance improvement when grepping huge files by disabling UTF-8, especially when doing `grep -i`

Answer (score 10):

Both of the implementations are in C, so a level playing field there.  Coreutils `sort` [apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/234054/unix-sort-algorithm-implementation) uses the [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm.  Mergesort does a fixed number of comparisons which increases logarithmically to the input size, i.e. [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)(n log n).

Python's sort uses a unique hybrid merge/insertion sort, [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which will do a variable number of comparisons with a best case scenario of O(n) -- presumably, on an already sorted list -- but is generally logarithmic (logically, you can't get better than logarithmic for the general case when sorting).

Given two different logarithmic sorts, one could have an advantage over the other on some particular data set.  A traditional merge sort does not vary, so it will perform the same regardless of the data, but e.g., quicksort (also logarithmic), which does vary, will perform better on some data but worse on others.

A factor of three (or more than 3, since `sort` is parallelized) is quite a bit though, which makes me wonder if there isn't some contingency here, such as `sort` swapping to disk (the `-T` option would seem to imply it does).  However, your low sys vs. user time implies this isn't the issue.

Comment: Good point that both implementations are written in C.  I'm sure if I implemented a sorting algorithm in Python it would be much, much slower.

Comment: By the way, the file consists of randomly generated float values between 0 and 1, so there shouldn't be too much structure to exploit.

Answer (score 8):

This is more of an extra analysis than an actual answer but it does seem to vary depending on the data being sorted. First, a base reading:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..1000000} > numbers.txt

$ time python sort.py <numbers.txt >s1.txt
real    0m0.521s
user    0m0.216s
sys     0m0.100s

$ time sort <numbers.txt >s2.txt
real    0m3.708s
user    0m4.908s
sys     0m0.156s
```

OK, python is *much* faster. However, you can make coreutils `sort` faster by telling it to sort numerically:

```
$ time sort <numbers.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m3.743s
user    0m4.964s
sys     0m0.148s

$ time sort -n <numbers.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m0.733s
user    0m0.836s
sys     0m0.100s
```

That's *much* faster but python still wins by a wide margin. Now, let's try again but with a non-sorted list of 1M numbers:

```
$ sort -R numbers.txt > randomized.txt

$ time sort -n <randomized.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m1.493s
user    0m1.920s
sys     0m0.116s

$ time python sort.py <randomized.txt >s1.txt
real    0m2.652s
user    0m1.988s
sys     0m0.064s
```

The coreutils `sort -n` is faster for unsorted numerical data (though you might be able to tweak the python sort's `cmp` parameter to make it faster). Coreutils `sort` is still significantly slower without the `-n` flag. So, what about random characters, not pure numbers?

```
$ tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c1000000 | 
    sed 's/./&\n/g' > random.txt

$ time sort  <random.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m2.487s
user    0m3.480s
sys     0m0.128s

$ time python sort.py  <random.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m1.314s
user    0m0.744s
sys     0m0.068s
```

Python still beats coreutils but by a much smaller margin than what you show in your question. Surprisingly, it is still faster when looking at pure alphabetical data:

```
$ tr -dc 'A-Za-z' </dev/urandom | head -c1000000 |
    sed 's/./&\n/g' > letters.txt

$ time sort   <letters.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m2.561s
user    0m3.684s
sys     0m0.100s

$ time python sort.py <letters.txt >s1.txt
real    0m1.297s
user    0m0.744s
sys     0m0.064s
```

It is also important to note that the two don't produce the same sorted output:

```
$ echo -e "A\nB\na\nb\n-" | sort -n
-
a
A
b
B

$ echo -e "A\nB\na\nb\n-" | python sort.py 
-
A
B
a
b
```

Oddly enough, the `--buffer-size` option didn't seem to make much (or any) difference in my tests. In conclusion, presumably because of the different algorithms mentioned in goldilock's answer, python `sort` seems to be faster in most cases but *numerical* GNU `sort` beats it on unsorted numbers<sup>1</sup>.

---

The OP has probably [found the root cause](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169758/22222) but for the sake of completeness, here's a final comparison:

```
$ time LC_ALL=C sort   <letters.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m0.280s
user    0m0.512s
sys     0m0.084s


$ time LC_ALL=C python sort.py   <letters.txt >s2.txt 
real    0m0.493s
user    0m0.448s
sys     0m0.044s
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Someone with more python-fu than I should try to test tweaking `list.sort()` to see of the same speed can be achieved by specifying the sorting method.</sub>

Comment: Python sort has an additional speed advantage, based on your last sample:  ASCII numerical order.  `sort` seems to be doing a bit of extra work for uppercase/lowercase comparisons.

Comment: @Izkata That's it!  See my answer below.

Comment: Actually python has quite a bit of overhead creating its internal strings out of the raw `stdin` input. Converting those to numbers (`lines = map(int, list(stdin))`) and back (`stdout.writelines(map(str,lines))`) makes the whole sorting go slower, **up** from 0.234s real to 0.720s on my machine.

Comment: Nice analysis. At the end of the day I'll take either Python `list.sort()` or coreutil's `sort` over bubble sorting a string array using bash (yuk!)